# How to fill a pandas data frame when the columns are not known before

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating with a for loop over a table with a html file and I have the following values in variables `name`, `gene_name_1`, `value1`, `gene_name_2`, `value2` in the first iteration.

`keyX` and `valueX` are part of a dictionary but I don't know how many keys and values are present for each iteration.

My idea was to use a dictionary which looks more or less like this:

```
d = {'gene_name_1': 2, 'gene_name_2': 5}
```

But now I realize that the values of the dictionary would change in every loop iteration, so it could look like this in the next loop:

```
d = {'gene_name_1': 3, 'gene_name_2': 0, 'gene_name_3': 9}
```

So I am not quite sure if a dictionary is the best data structure here:

What I would like to obtain is a pandas data frame which looks more or less like this.

```
          | gene_name_1 | gene_name_2 | gene_name_3 | ...
organism1 |           2 |           5 |           0 | ...
organism2 |           3 |           0 |           9 | ...
...
```

Just to clarify: 0 is for those names where the key does not appear.

My problem is, I don't know the column names or the amount of columns. I wanted to start with an empty data frame, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

How can I start on a data frame where I don't know the names or the amount of columns?

I hope this was understandable, if I should clarify somehow, please let me know.

Comment: It would be nice if you could make a comment when you downvote, so I can improve it.

Comment: Can you add sample of `dict`? I think `DataFrame` should be generated from `dict`, so not necessery define columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need create list of `dict`s and pass it to `DataFrame` constructor, last replace `NaN` to `0` by `fillna`:

```
d = {'gene_name_1': 2, 'gene_name_2': 5}
d1 = {'gene_name_1': 3, 'gene_name_2': 0, 'gene_name_3': 9}

#use loop
L = [d, d1]

df = pd.DataFrame(L).fillna(0)
print (df)
   gene_name_1  gene_name_2  gene_name_3
0            2            5          0.0
1            3            0          9.0
```